# AngularJS Routing Issues

Tags: angularjs, routes

so I am trying to figure out routing and right now I could get it to work for basic stuff like `www.sdfsfsfs.com/route1` doing

```
.when("/route1",{
    templateUrl: "route1.html"
})
```

But am stuck on trying to figure out how to do something like `www.sdfsfsfs.com/route1/jpera`. I could get it to work by creating a route1 directory and then putting jpera inside that directory so then it would be

```
.when("/route1/jpera",{
    templateUrl: "jpera.html"

})
```

but then the route to the url with `/route1` gets messed up and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You mean you want nested routing?

Comment: For nesting routing you need to use `ui-router`.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma that is completely incorrect. See the example here ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Comment: You want nested routing or want to pass parameters with route @HiThere

Answer (score 1):

In angular-ui-router, u can do this like this:

```
angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
....
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'dir1/dir2/home.html', 
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .state('home.page1', {
        url: '/page1',
        templateUrl: 'dir1/dir2/page1.html',        
        controller: 'page1Controller'
    })
...

function homeController($scope){
//do something
}   

function page1Controller($scope){
//do something
}
```

So, page1 is a child view of the home.

Else, if you wanna use partial templates into a layout template, u can use views like these:-

```
.state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                //templateUrl declared here will not be picked up
    views: {
                    //main layout template
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'dir1/dir2/home.controller.html',
                        controller: 'homeCtrl',
                        controllerAs: 'vm'
                    },
                    //page1@home. //partial template.
                    'page1@home':  {
                        templateUrl: 'dir1/dir2/page1.controller.html',
                        controller: 'page1Ctrl',
                        controllerAs: 'vm'
                    },
                    ...

        } 
})
```

Hope this gives u some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I angular ui router it's pretty easy.

Here is documentation of nested routing.
 https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views

Hope it helps.